# Slow Rails JSON Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, json

I've got a slow action in Rails. The view / active record and sphinx all report a fast rendering yet the overall action takes around 1.2 seconds. Not great at all. I'm wondering if it might be because I'm converting a large active record set into JSON. Here's my log output

```
Started GET "/genres/popular?page=2&per_page=10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-17 17:53:04 +1000
[Barista] Compiling all scripts for barista
[Barista] Compiling all coffeescripts
Processing by GenresController#popular as JSON
Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "per_page"=>"10"}
Genre Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` ORDER BY medias_count DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `genres`
Media Load (2.2ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 209)
Genre Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
MediaType Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 209) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Media Load (3.7ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 14)
Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 14) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Media Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 286)
Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 286) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Media Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 264)
Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 264) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Media Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 270)
Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 270) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Media Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 271)
Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 271) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Media Load (2.1ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 36)
Genre Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 36) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Media Load (2.1ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 58)
Genre Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 58) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Media Load (2.2ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 186)
Genre Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 186) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Media Load (3.4ms)  SELECT `medias`.* FROM `medias` WHERE (`medias`.genre_id = 10)
Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 10) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 10) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 10) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 10) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 10) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 10) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 10) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 10) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` WHERE (`genres`.`id` = 10) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `media_types`.* FROM `media_types` WHERE (`media_types`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 1262ms (Views: 209.9ms | ActiveRecord: 28.2ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: That's a lot of SQL. Have you considered using :includes=>'genres' in your AR query. Could you post your action controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I just needed to eager load the medias. Rails 101.

Comment: It did. I also stopped loading all the associated medias when loading the genres and I'm in the process of rewriting the only item that relies on that behaviour. That more then anything sped things up because I was crunching 250k of data in JSON (and sending that to the client!!!)